# Sencha Compile issue while deploying web application using ./make_bootstrap.sh; ./make_compile.sh

Tags: javascript, extjs, compilation, compression

Hi I am working on a web application that is implemented in Ext-JS. I deployed the application using Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250 with command ./make_bootstrap.sh; ./make_compile.sh
No issues during the deployment.

The application can be accessed using the test link //mainApplication/app/index_debug.html or //mainApplication/app (accesses all-classes.js) url....

When the app is deployed it compresses all javaScript files into one file which is all-classes.js. The deployment was successful. But when I access the app from the url ://mainApplication/app/... it shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null all-classes.js:1
Ext.define.initContainerall-classes.js:1
Ext.define.renderall-classes.js:1
Ext.define.doAutoRenderall-classes.js:1
Ext.define.showall-classes.js:1
(anonymous function)all-classes.js:1
TableManager::findTables() content.scripts.c.js:11
```

However if I access the app using ://myApplication/app/index_debug.html, it works fine. This is for testing purpose and it loads all js files individually unlike accessing through all-classes.js

I have browsed through the web for similar error. But haven't found any at this level. If the application is accessible through index_debug.html why would it not be accessible with the same javaScript files but compressed?

Comment: Don't you have any warning in the console with index_debug.html? Something along the line "class XXX has been loaded synchronously, consider using Ext.require etc."?

Comment: You are right. I get the same warning in the console for index_debug.html as well, even though it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compressed all-classes.js obviously removes all whitespace and hence it is just a one line code when formatting (using Sublime Text's JSFormatter package) becomes thousands of lines. Since it was one line I couldn't find what the browser is complaining about. I formatted the code and ran the application. And found exactly in which line it failed. It was pointing to an anonymous function. Once I remove the function the app started working... So the tip here is to format the compressed code when debugging in firebug or chrome developer tool.